# Facebook/GooglePlus SHA1 key in an Android library project

Tags: android, android-library, android-facebook

We're creating an Android SDK which is represented as a library project and one of its features is sharing.

While integrating with Facebook and GooglePlus, the project SHA1 hash key is requested.

Would it be possible to use our own SHA1 hash key while embedded in other Android applications? we'd like to keep the sharing feature under our brand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer to this link.It will help  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: you must use your own sha1

Comment: @Naveen Could you please elaborate why do you think it will help. the page explains how to integrate Facebook SDK with a standalone application while I'm trying to figure out how to use my hash key while hosted in another application. Thanks!

Comment: @RahulChaudhary, when you say "your own sha1" do you mean the hosted application or the library project? Thanks!

Comment: its your id sha1 like eclipse os android studio

Comment: @RahulChaudhary could you please explain how it will work.
As the library project will integrate with the Facebook SDK and the hosting application will probably also

Comment: hosting application means  your app?????

Comment: No. I've got a library project which will act as an SDK. It will be included in other applications which will include it in their main project.